# Nginx + php-fpm high cpu usage

Tags: php, nginx, cpu

Nginx.conf

```
 # Server globals
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;


# Worker config
events {
        worker_connections  1024;
        use                 epoll;
        multi_accept        on;
}


http {
    # Main settings
    sendfile                        on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    client_header_timeout           1m;
    client_body_timeout             1m;
    client_header_buffer_size       2k;
    client_body_buffer_size         256k;
    client_max_body_size            256m;
    large_client_header_buffers     4   8k;
    send_timeout                    30;
    keepalive_timeout               90 90;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    server_tokens                   off;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    server_names_hash_max_size      512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   512;


    # Log format
    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                        '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  bytes   '$body_bytes_sent';
    #access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    access_log off;


    # Mime settings
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


    # Compression
    gzip                on;
    gzip_comp_level     9;
    gzip_min_length     512;
    gzip_buffers        8 64k;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css text/javascript text/js text/xml application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/x-font-ttf application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig image/svg+xml font/opentype;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";


    # Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout  90;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_buffers       32 4k;


    # Cloudflare https://www.cloudflare.com/ips
    set_real_ip_from   103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   104.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   131.0.72.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from   162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from   172.64.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from   173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from   197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from   198.41.128.0/17;
    #set_real_ip_from   2400:cb00::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2606:4700::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2803:f800::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2405:b500::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2405:8100::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2c0f:f248::/32;
    #set_real_ip_from   2a06:98c0::/29;
    real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;


    # SSL PCI Compliance
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers        "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";


    # Error pages
    error_page          403          /error/403.html;
    error_page          404          /error/404.html;
    error_page          502 503 504  /error/50x.html;


    # Cache settings
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=60m max_size=1024m;
    proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
    proxy_temp_path  /var/cache/nginx/temp;
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1d;


    # Cache bypass
    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 0;
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }


    # File cache settings
    open_file_cache          max=10000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid    60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   off;


    # Wildcard include
    include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and this is a problem rewrite to php file in my domain.conf

```
location / {
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return  404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9008;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    }       
}   

location /config/config.txt {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /config/config.php;
    }
```

The problem is when a lot of users connects to the server the cpu load of nginx worker proccess increase up to 100%

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
20113 nginx     20   0 72204 6156  952 S 65.4  0.2   0:20.69 nginx: worker process
20111 nginx     20   0 72048 6076  956 S 62.1  0.2   0:39.13 nginx: worker process
20110 nginx     20   0 71060 5216  952 S 57.8  0.1   0:19.15 nginx: worker process
20112 nginx     20   0 70996 5152  952 S 44.6  0.1   0:20.91 nginx: worker process
20114 nginx     20   0 70740 4736  964 R 21.5  0.1   0:20.35 nginx: worker process
20109 nginx     20   0 71260 5200  952 S 17.5  0.1   0:22.48 nginx: worker process
```

The php script uses readfile() function and return data acording several parameters (geo, user agent etc)

Can anybody help to solve the problem with the nginx cpu high load?

Update - the php code:

```
<?php
    $time = 10e6;
    $uid = 'uid';

    $config_aa    = 'aa/config_aa.js';
    $config_bb    = 'bb/config_bb.js';
    $config_cc    = 'cc/config_cc.js';
    $config_other = 'other/config_other.json';


    $COUNTRY_CODE = isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"] : $COUNTRY_CODE = 'UNDEFINED';

    if ($COUNTRY_CODE == 'AA' || $COUNTRY_CODE == 'UNDEFINED') {
        if (round(microtime(true) * 1000) - $_GET[$uid] > $time ) {
                header('Content-type: application/javascript');
                readfile($config_aa);
                readfile($config_bb);           
                exit;
            }
            else {
                header('Content-type: application/javascript');
                readfile($config_cc);
                exit;
            }
    }

    if ($COUNTRY_CODE == 'BB') {
        if (round(microtime(true) * 1000) - $_GET[$uid] > $time ) {
                header('Content-type: application/javascript');
                readfile($config_aa);
                readfile($config_bb);           
                exit;
            }
            else {
                header('Content-type: application/javascript');
                readfile($config_cc);
                exit;
            }
    }

    header('Content-type: no-javascripts-no-custom text/plain');
    readfile($config_other);
    exit;


?>
```

Comment: This is probably something related to the PHP script, not nginx+fpm... Can you share some code? This usually happens in high concurrency situations when either the PHP script takes too long to run or something the script needs (filesystem, database, etc) is overloaded, which causes the overload to move onto PHP. A full output from `top` and the actual PHP code would help. It's hard to diagnose otherwise

Comment: I added the php code.